# Customer specific product offering - Best practice

Tags: product-attribute, multistore, catalog

To build an **e-commerce** site that offers a specific set of **products** for each **state** of a **country**, what would be the best practice to be followed from below listed approaches (or another approach) to create the product catalog.

Approaches

1. Define each state as root category and then create products under desired subcategories
2. Define a single root category and then create products under desired subcategories. Define a custom multi-select "Available State" attribute and tag the product to respective state.
3. Create a multi-store site where each state is represented as a store and then create desired products for each store.